# Alter node before render or after save

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I need to alter the content of a node either before it is viewed or after it is saved. In order alter the fields I will need the create date of the node. I am currently attempting to do this via [`hook_node_view`](http://api.drupal.org/hook_node_view), but is there a better way?

Comment: Are you using Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: Drupal version 7.

Answer (score 1):

[hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) can help you making the changes

> Act on a node being inserted or updated. This hook is invoked from node_save() before the node is saved to the
>   database.

so inside this hook you can get the created time and can change the title.

As an example code: Here I am making node title as the time article node is created.

```
function mymodulename_node_presave($node) {
  if($node->type == "article") {
    $node->title = $node->created;
  }
}
```

**Make sure you do not call node_save() inside this function, else this will turn out to non breking recursion.**

Comment: Is it possible to do this shorter? To only speak to article node and no need to check if node == article?

Answer (score 0):

[hook_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) responds to the creation of a new node.

This hook is invoked from [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/7) after the node is inserted into the node table in the database, after the type-specific [hook_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_insert/7) is invoked, and after [field_attach_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_insert/7) is called.

Comment: Laxman13, I tried using hook_node_insert() unsuccessfully. Here is more detail about what I want to do, whenever a node(article) is created, I would like to get its created date and depending on the date change the value of certain content in the node-say the title for example. So, when the node is saved and displayed in the browser the title should be changed. I was somewhat able to accomplish this with hook_node_view. With hook_node_view when I save the node the database value is changed but the browser does not reflect the change. When I refresh the browser the new database value is shown.

Comment: No @gilzero, hook_node_insert is invoked before the node is saved, not after it. I had a long email process telling users that the new node was created, taking 5 minutes, inside hook_node_insert but the people who got the email and went to the site didn't see the email until the process was finished.